# Do I always have to use a unique_ptr to express ownership?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Lets say I have a class A that owns an object of class B.

- A is responsible for creating and deleting this object of B.
- The ownership must not be transferred to another class.
- The object of B will never be reinitialized after an object of A was created.

Normally, as far as I know, in modern C++ we would use a unique_ptr to express that A is the owner of this object / reference:

```cpp
// variant 1 (unique pointer)
class A {
  public:
    A(int param) : b(std::make_unique<B>(param)) {}

    // give out a raw pointer, so that others can access and change the object 
    // (without transferring ownership)
    B* getB() {
      return b.get();
    }
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;
};
```

Someone suggested that I also may use this approach instead:

```cpp
// variant 2 (no pointer)
class A {
  public:
    A(int param) : b(B(param)) {}

    // give out a reference, so that others can access and change the object 
    // (without transferring ownership)
    B& getB() {
      return b;
    }
  private:
    B b;
};
```

As far as I understand the main differences are that in variant 2, the memory is allocated coherently, while in variant 1 the memory for the B object can be allocated anywhere and the pointer must be resolved first in order to find it.
Also of course, it makes a difference if users of A's public interface can work with a `B*` or a `B&`.
But in both cases, I am sure that ownership stays within A as I need it.

Do I always have to use variant 1 (unique_ptrs) to express ownership?
What are reasons to use variant 2 over variant 1?

Comment: It’s the other way round: if you *can* use variant 2 (storing a value), you should *never* use variant 1 (storing a pointer). `std::unique_ptr` is only for cases where you can’t store a value (e.g. runtime polymorphism, dynamic object lifetime …).

Comment: Variant 2 is the go to approach.  variant 1 is only needed if you need to hold a polymorphic object, or the object is very large and you don't want it tacking up stack space, or if the object is not able to be copied or moved, but you want to be able to do that with the class that contains the object.

Comment: Variant `1` in general is pointless. It can be used to isolate some details form header file, but the true power of pointers in this scenario is shown when polymorphism is used.

Comment: *"Also of course, it makes a difference if users of A's public interface can work with a B\* or a B&"* - That's entirely a non-issue. You can hand out pointers to the direct member `&b`, or deference the pointer `*b` to return a reference (null pointer caveat of course).

Comment: Not related to your question, but I think the quote in your profile's about field is my new favorite saying : *"Anything seems possible if you don't know what you are talking about"*

Comment: Notice that in your variant2, `A` is copiable/movable (assuming `B` is), whereas in variant1, A is movable (even with non-movable `B`) and not copiable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you're right. Maybe something like a safer Non-owning pointer class might be useful here, i.e. kind of a reference to unique_ptr quality.

Comment: @Secundi In modern C++, a widely held convention is that raw pointers fill the role of a non-owning pointer class that you are describing. When this convention is applied, you simply never call `delete`. If a pointer would be owning, it is required to be an owning smart pointer instead, so the cleanup is implied.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes for sure, but the deletion might be subtile in doubt and not easy to see, for instance via a forward to a sharedPtr-constructor. Maybe the current smart pointers are really sufficient here, I'm just not convinced in all.

Comment: The public interface can be exactly identical in both cases. The only significant difference is whether `b` can be a `nullptr` or not. With a `unique_ptr` it can be “absent” (`nullptr`). With direct nesting it must be always present (and properly initialized). In this case the public API doesn’t make it possible to *not* have `b`, so direct nesting appears to be a more appropriate choice. Unless of course `B` has an overloaded `new` operator and needs a very special type of allocation (e.g. shared with a GPU with very special alignment requirements etc. etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ownership can be expressed in different ways.

Your `B b` of variant 2 is the simplest form of ownership. The instance of class `A` exclusively owns the object stored in `b` and the ownership cannot be transferred to another object or (member) variable.

`std::unique_ptr<B> b` expresses an unique - but transferable - ownership over the object managed by `std::unique_ptr<B>`.

But also `std::optional<B>`, `std::vector<B>`, … or `std::variant<B,C>`, expresses ownership.

> Also of course, it makes a difference if users of A's public interface can work with a B* or a B&. But in both cases, I am sure that ownership stays within A as I need it.

You can always create a member function that returns `B*` no matter if the member is `B b`, or `std::unique_ptr<B> b` (or also for `std::optional<B>`, `std::vector<B>`,  … `std::variant<B,C>`)

Interestingly this code:

**Variant 1**

```
class A {
  public:
    A(int param) : b(B(param)) {}

    // give out a reference, so that others can access and change the object 
    B& getBRef() {
      return b;
    }


    B* getB() {
      return &b;
    }
  private:
    B b;
};
```

can be less problematic then:

**Variant 2**

```
class A {
  public:
    A(int param) : b(std::make_unique<B>(param)) {}

    // give out a raw pointer, so that others can access and change the object 
    // (without transferring ownership)
    B* getB() {
      return b.get();
    }
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;
};
```

For the **Variant 2** case, a call to another member function of `A` could potentially invalidate the pointer (if that function e.g. assigned another object to the `unique_ptr`). While for **Variant 1** the validity of the returned pointer (or reference) is given by the lifetime of an instance of `A`

In any case, you then have to treat `B *` as non owning raw pointer, and make clear in the documentation, how long that raw pointer is valid.

---

Which kind of ownership you choose depends on the actual use case.
Most of the time you will try to stay with the simplest ownership `B b`. If that object should be optional you will use `std::optional<B>`.

If the implementation requires it e.g. if you plan to use PImpl, if the data structure might prevent the use of `B b` (like in the case of tree- or graph-like structures), or if the owner-ship has to be transferable, you might want to use `std::unique_ptr<B>`.

Comment: 'and make clear in the documentation, how long that raw pointer is valid.' In my opinion, that feels a bit like a language flaw since the beginning of C/C++. Code should speak for itself as far as possible. The concept of object lifetime is (a core) part of the language itself. At latest since we have unique and shared pointers, I think a further non owning smart pointer would be very beneficial here.

Comment: @Secundi a non-owning smart pointer (at least like suggested by [std::experimental::observer_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr)) wouldn't help much. It wouldn't allow extending the lifetime of `unique_ptr` because it would somehow contradict the meaning of a `unique_ptr`. The `observer_ptr` in its current form is basically just a raw pointer with the semantic information that it has no ownership.  With `std::shard_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` you have such a concept with its downsides.

Comment: I did not mean life time extension. Yes, the observer seems to be what I had in mind, thanks for the information!

Comment: @Secundi you would need something like the borrow check concept that exists in Rust. Interestingly returning `B*` for a member `B a` is less problematic than returning `B *` for `std::unique_ptr<B> b`.

Comment: @Secundi A rule of thumb is that if a code-base uses smart-pointers, then it should be designed so that any raw pointer is a non-owning pointer. `I did not mean lifetime extension.` but then what should the advantage of the `observer_ptr`  be if your concern was my statement `and make clear in the documentation, how long that raw pointer is valid.`. The `observer_ptr` wouldn't change anything about that, it would _"just"_ add the semantic information that the returned pointer isn't an owning pointer, but does not give any insights about how long it will be valid.

Comment: 'A rule of thumb is that if a code-base uses smart-pointers, then it should be designed so that any raw pointer is a non-owning pointer. ' Yes, maybe it's more my feeling than a full rationale, that "nacked pointers" beyond interface layers at least are suspicious things (for internal private very locale implementations, I fully understand your points!). I just want to emphasize that validity of the pointer itself is not my point here. It's clear, that this kind of quality requires a wrapping for instance, providing this information if required.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the point of `unique_ptr`. It was precisely created to allow ownership transfer via a simple assignation. If ownership has never to be transfered it is much simpler to have a subobject by using containment.

Memory allocation does not really matter in C++ at least for a programmer *using* an object, because many objects internally use dynamic allocation whatever the duration of the object is. An example is `std::string`. In most implementations, an automatic `std::string` object will still use dynamic memory for its underlying character array.

---

Of course library implementors should care for the way *their* object use dynamic memory. Small String Optimization was invented in  recent implementation of the standard library to avoid dynamic allocation for small strings (thanks to NathanOliver for its comment).

Comment: Regarding your string example, SSO was allowed exactly because dynamic allocation does matter.  It's a lot more costly to allocate memory then to increment the stack pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I am afraid that my wording was bad. What I meant is that the programmer should not care for the underlying allocation details. And my example was just showing that they could not control it, because only the implementor of any contained object could. I have tried to make it more clear, but feel free to edit my post if it is not. Even if I try hard to write correct English, it is not my first language.